# How to break out of nested loops?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Is there a way in Godot's GDScript to quickly/easily break out of nested loops?

For example:

```
# Check if the entire grid is filled.
filled = true
for x in grid:
    for y in grid[x]:
        if grid[x][y] == null:
            filled = false
            break # Break out of both loops?
```

PHP's `break` has an optional numeric argument that allows breaking out of nested loops: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php
And Python has a `for...else` construct that can be used for this purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150107/4168619

Is there anything similar in GDScript?

Answer (score 6):

#### Option1 Use an extra bool flag to break

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    var grid = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,null,9],
    ]
    var filled = true
    for row in grid:
        var isBreak = false
        for data in row:
            if data == null:
                filled = false
                isBreak = true
                break
        if isBreak:
            break
    print(filled)
```

#### Option2 Use return

```
extends Node2D

func isFilled(array):
    for row in array:
        for data in row:
            if data == null:
                return false
    return true

func _ready():
    var grid = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,null,9],
    ]
    var filled = isFilled(grid)
    print(filled)
```

#### Option3 flatten the array and use a single loop

(use `append` or `append_array` or `+`):

```
extends Node2D

func flatten1(array):
    var result =[]
    for row in array:
        for data in row:
            result.append(data)
    return result

func flatten2(array):
    var result =[]
    for row in array:
        result.append_array(row)
    return result
    
func flatten3(array):
    var result =[]
    for row in array:
        result+=row
    return result
    
func _ready():
    var grid = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,null,9],
    ]
    var filled = true
    for element in flatten1(grid):
        if element==null:
            filled = false
            break
    print(filled)
```

(use `reduce`):

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    var grid = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,null,9],
    ]
    var filled = true
    for element in grid.reduce(func(acc, x): return x+acc):
        if element==null:
            filled = false
            break
    print(filled)
```

#### Option4 Just check if the entire grid is filled

(use `reduce` and `has`)

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    var grid = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,null,9],
    ]
    var filled = !grid.reduce(func(acc, x): return x+acc).has(null)
    print(filled)
```

Related link: [Godot Engine 4.0 documentation:Array](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_array.html)

Answer (score 2):

Some languages, such as `C#`, doesn't have such feature, but there are workarounds.

I'd prefer to put the code in a seperate function, and then use `return;` or `return [value];` the moment you got the value you wanted.

Going through each loop with a boolean check (like `if (filled == false) break;`) is also possible in larger nested loops.

Comment: C# has such a feature, it's just not considered good coding style in many cases: `goto` will break out of any number of nested loops. As long as you only ever use forward `goto`s, (jumping to a label strictly later in the same function), you avoid the worst problems with them. But it's still usually a code smell and a sign that there's a better way to structure the algorithm so that you don't need it, like your `return` suggestion.

Comment: I've been strictly teached to never use `goto` in any scenario, for the reasons you mentioned. So even suggesting `goto` as an option would've been a bad habit for me. But yeah, technically it is an option.